# jQuery detect a class that is added by jQuery itself

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a form which need to add fields dynamically with + / - (plus, minus) button.

The code is adding fields perfectly but when I try to remove it, it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
 <div class="jfs_product_detail_fields">
                    <span class="jfs_product_name"><input type="text" name="product name" placeholder="Product Name"></span>
                    <span class="jfs_product_id"><input type="text" name="product ID" placeholder="Product ID#"></span>
                    <span class="jfs_qty"><input type="text" name="Qty" placeholder="Quantity"></span>
                    <button class="jfs_btn">+</button>
                    <div class="jfs_clr"></div>
                </div>
```

JQUERY

```
// making them unique
var num = 1;

// cloning
jQuery('.jfs_btn').on('click', function () {
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('jfs_remove')) {
        alert('test');
    } else {
        var fields = '<div id="jfs_product_detail_fields"><span class="jfs_product_name"><input type="text" name="product_name_' + num + '" placeholder="Product Name"></span><span class="jfs_product_id"><input type="text" name="product_id_' + num + '" placeholder="Product ID#"></span><span class="jfs_qty"><input type="text" name="qty_' + num + '" placeholder="Quantity"></span><button class="jfs_btn jfs_remove">-</button><div class="jfs_clr"></div></div>';
        num = num + 1;
        jQuery('.jfs_product_detail_fields:first').before(fields);
    }
});
```

Here is my code on JS Fiddle also: [My Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/64sfpf5j/)

Any help or tip will be appreciated :)

Omer

Comment: For dynamic elements, use event propagation on existing parent element. jQuery(document).on('click', '.jfs_btn',function () {

Comment: What do you mean by event propagation?

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/64sfpf5j/1/

Remove button is dynamically created, so you should use `.on()` method like this:

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.jfs_remove', function () {

    $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

Comment: I did use .on() but it wasn't working for me...

`$('.jfs_remove').on('click', function(){
     alert('test');
})`

Comment: Why did you use **"body"** as a selector?

Comment: @Omer because `body` contains the dynamic elements with `.jfs_remove` class, it could be any non-dynamic element that contains the dynamic elements with `.jfs_remove` class